# Apache mod_proxy with Redmine on sub-URI

Tags: apache, redmine, mod-proxy

I must have read every single article on the internet regarding Redmine and Apache and I still cant get it to work!

I have Redmine running on `http://server:3000` perfectly using Thin.  We have another Apache service on the same server which hosts our internal web tools on a different port (8096) so I would like Redmine to follow the same convention.

In that respect on Apache in httpd.conf I've added:

```
ProxyPass /redmine http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPassReverse /redmine http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPreserveHost on
```

Which seems to work fine.  If you type in `http://server:8096/redmine` it will bring up the Redmine start page,  but clicking on any other link results is a **404**.

It looks like its not appending the /redmine on links from the site as clicking on the 'admin' link takes me too `http://server:8096/admin` instead of `http://server:8096/redmine/admin`

I've also looked into adding any of the three below to **config/environment.rb** but there seems to be conflicting info on which to use,  and none of them seem to:

```
ActionController::AbstractRequest.relative_url_root = "/redmine" 
ActionController::Base.relative_url_root = "/redmine" 
Redmine::Utils::relative_url_root = "/redmine"
```

As always any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit::

I am also trialling out

```
ProxyPass /redmine http://server:3000
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://server:3000 /redmine
<Location /redmine>
    ProxyPassReverse http://server:3000
    SetOutputFilter proxy-html
    ProxyHTMLURLMap /               /redmine/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap /redmine/       /redmine
</Location>
```

but seems to have the same result.  Interestingly,  if I access `http://localhost:8096/redmine` from the local server all the links seems to work and direct to the correct page,  except the CSS and JS is not working.

If remotely I manually type in any of the links `http://server:8096/redmine/admin` then I get the correct page with CSS etc,  it's just the linking between pages that isn't working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man, I've never seen an working setup of apache proxy changing context like this:

```
ProxyPass /redmine http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

This should work:

```
ProxyPass /redmine http://127.0.0.1:3000/redmine
```

To do that, you need to setup your backend server (mongrel or whatever) to work on a sub-uri.

I would suggest you to use mod_passenger instead. This is the easiest way to setup redmine and it doesn't involve proxy. Here follows my setup:

```
brunojcm@brunojcm-htpc:~$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/redmine 
<Directory /var/www/redmine>
    RailsBaseURI /redmine
    PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
</Directory>
```

Where `/var/www/redmine` is a link to your public redmine folder.

```
brunojcm@brunojcm-htpc:~$ ll /var/www/redmine
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Sep  4  2011 /var/www/redmine -> /opt/redmine/current/public/
```

You will also need to install mod_passenger. I don't remember exactly how to do it, but I believe you need to `gem install passenger` and after run `passenger-install-apache2-module` and follow the instructions.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Your right,  I had set that up when I was testing without the sub-uri.  I'm currently running Thin with the parameter --prefix /redmine with the proxypass config that you stated above and it is working correctly!

Comment: Hi @mhouston100 , i have the same problem could you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861322/apache2-2-thin-railsapp-sub-uri-windows-server-2003 thanks in advance